# Can I disable spam filtering for one user in Exchange Online Protecttion?

Tags: spam-filter, exchangeonline

We are using Exchange Online Protection in front of our on-premises mailserver. Is it possible to disable the spam filtering for one user only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Is it possible to disable the spam filtering for one user only?” This user is in your organization or external user?

Every organization has a built-in anti-spam policy named Default, it is applied to all recipients in the organization, even though there's no spam filter rule (recipient filters) associated with the policy. And you can't delete the default policy. You could create a custom policy without spam filter rule, then apply it to this user.

You can also create transport rules to bypass spam filtering for messages matching a given criteria.
https://help.comodo.com/topic-290-1-932-12710-.html